# How to scale imageView out side of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to scale my ImageView outside of RelativeLayout to show half of Circle
to the `alignParentButtom` of `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="1049dp"
        android:layout_height="784dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_brightness_1_black_24dp" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do provide an image of what you want!

Comment: You can take `<ImageView>` as ParentLayout because `Child` can't be big ever then `Parent`.

Comment: add an image to your desired output

Comment: I don't have the reputation to upload that image to show you what I want. I want to show half of this ```ImageView``` in ```RelativeLayout``` in position ```alignParentButton```

Answer (score 0):

To get your desire result, do as below ...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="1049dp"
    android:layout_height="784dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/tv_no_of_person"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView4"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/circle"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Above code can help you to get view at align bottom of any view(Here Imageview).

[image: It will show Like this Image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but If this black circle show in the bottom center and half of the circle hide and half of the others show in the layout that will be correct.

Comment: Hello@CodeCool, Can you Share Image or preview of view you actually want?

Comment: this is the image of I want you to see red circle in bottom I want looks like this https://res.cloudinary.com/www-paypolsoftware-com/image/upload/v1569410888/Screenshot_20190925-155508_Blood_Bank_cc2cpd.jpg